# What is it called when a case class constructor param is used outside the class?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class

What happens in line nine below that makes the `result` variable accessible on line ten?

The example is from the [Akka documentation on testing](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html). The `Ask` in line eight returns a `scala.concurrent.Future`. The `Future.value()` returns an [Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/scala/Option.html)[[Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/scala/util/Try.html)[T]], which will either be `Some(Success(t))` or `Some(Failure(error))`. Then `Some.get` is called, which should either return the `t` or the error, depending the result of the `Try`.

It seems like whether or not the value of `future.value.get` is an error in line nine, it is attempting to instantiate a new Success, [which is defined as a case class in Try](http://www.codatlas.com/github.com/scala/scala/2.11.x/src/library/scala/util/Try.scala?keyword=success&line=224), with the return value from `Some.get`. The Success on line nine is not used directly, but instead the case class constructor parameter `result` somehow makes it into scope so it can be used in line ten. What is this called in Scala? Where can I find out more about how this syntax works?

```
1.  import akka.testkit.TestActorRef
2.  import scala.concurrent.duration._
3.  import scala.concurrent.Await
4.  import akka.pattern.ask
5.  
6.  val actorRef = TestActorRef(newMyActor)
7.  // hypothetical message stimulating a '42' answer
8.  val future = actorRef ? Say42
9.  val Success( result: Int ) = future.value.get
10. result should be (42)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`val Success( result: Int ) = future.value.get` is a pattern match. You can use pattern-matching to assign values to identifiers when declaring a val. It's about the same as writing:

```
val result: Int = future.value.get match {
    case Success(r: Int) => r
}
```

Notice how this is not an exhaustive match, though, and if `future.value.get` is a `Failure`, then a `MatchError` will be thrown. In the context of unit tests, I use pattern matching like this all the time, since a `MatchError` would be another indication of failure.

Here are a few examples of similar (safer) pattern-matching assignments:

```
 val (a, b) = (1, 2)

 case class Test(i: Int, j: String)
 val test = Test(1, "a")
 val (i, j) = test

 val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
 val List(first, second, _*) = list // though this will fail if the List has less than 3 elements
```

Answer (score 1):

That's just pattern matching. For instance:

```
 scala> val Some(a) = Some(5)
 a: Int = 5

 scala> val Some(a) = None: Option[Int]
 scala.MatchError: None (of class scala.None$)
 ... 33 elided
```

is equivalent to:

```
scala> val a = Some(5) match {case Some(a) => a}
a: Int = 5

scala> val a = (None: Option[Int]) match {case Some(a) => a}
scala.MatchError: None (of class scala.None$)
  ... 33 elided
```

in both cases [`Some.unapply`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html) method (which is part of companion-object, generated automatically for case class) is called.

In general, for an expression like `val Extractor(a, Extractor(b, c)) = input` scala-compiler internally generates (you may check it with macros) special synthetic expressions:

```
val tuple = input match { //synthetic value here
    Extractor(a, Extractor(b, c)) => (a,b,c)
}
val a = tuple._1
val b = tuple._2
val c = tuple._3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Pattern Matching](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html).